# Get attribute name value of <input>

Tags: jquery

How to get the attribute name value of a input tag using jQuery. Please help.

```html
<input name="xxxxx" value="1">
```

Comment: Shortcut: https://gist.github.com/ykessler/52f8af9877a216a9169c9704b57ebf9e

Answer (score 322, accepted):

Give your input an ID and use the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
var name = $("#id").attr("name");
```

Comment: I am surprised that this is the accepted answer, the input doesn't have an 'id' just a 'name' and a 'value'

Answer (score 46):

Use the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method of jQuery like this:

```
alert($('input').attr('name'));
```

Note that you can also use `attr` to set the attribute values by specifying second argument:

```
$('input').attr('name', 'new_name')
```

Answer (score 21):

While there is no denying that jQuery is a powerful tool, it is a really bad idea to use it for such a trivial operation as "get an element's attribute value".

Judging by the current accepted answer, I am going to assume that you were able to add an ID attribute to your element and use that to select it.

With that in mind, here are two pieces of code. First, the code given to you in the Accepted Answer:

```
$("#ID").attr("name");
```

And second, the [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) version of it:

```
document.getElementById('ID').getAttribute("name");
```

My results:

- jQuery: 300k operations / second
- JavaScript: 11,000k operations / second

You can test for yourself [here](http://jsperf.com/attr-getattribute-test). The "plain JavaScript" vesion is **over 35 times faster** than the jQuery version.

Now, that's just for one operation, over time you will have more and more stuff going on in your code. Perhaps for something particularly advanced, the optimal "pure JavaScript" solution would take one second to run. The jQuery version might take 30 seconds to a whole minute! That's huge! People aren't going to sit around for that. Even the browser will get bored and offer you the option to kill the webpage for taking too long!

As I said, jQuery is a powerful tool, but it should *not* be considered [the answer to everything](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif).

Comment: nice answer, i cross checked so javascript is more faster than jquery right?

Comment: You answered this question 4 years after the question was asked and you didn't address the question. The person asked how to do it in jQuery. It's up to the programmer whether to use jQuery or Vanilla JS and is outside the scope of the question

Comment: Vanilla JS!?? kidding, I spent half an hour researching what the hack Vanilla JS is.

Comment: Perhaps the developer doesn't know. I was aware of the fact that frameworks like jQuery cause some overhead. But I hadn't expected slowing down such simple tasks in factor **35** when using jQuery...

Answer (score 20):

```
var value_input = $("input[name*='xxxx']").val();
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short / only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: It actually doesn't solve the problem. OP wants to get the name value; this assumes you already know it.

Comment: This does not get the value of 'name' attribute

Answer (score 7):

You need to write a selector which selects the correct `<input>` first.  Ideally you use the element's ID `$('#element_id')`, failing that the ID of it's container `$('#container_id input')`, or the element's class `$('input.class_name')`.

Your element has none of these and no context, so it's hard to tell you how to select it.

Once you have figured out the proper selector, you'd use the [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to access the element's attributes.  To get the name, you'd use `$(selector).attr('name')` which would return (in your example) `'xxxxx'`.

Answer (score 5):

A better way could be using 'this', it takes whatever the name of the 'id' is and uses that. As long as you add the class name called 'mytarget'.

Whenever any of the fields that have target change then it will show an alert box with the name of that field. Just cut and past whole script for it to work!

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.mytarget').change(function() {
var name1 = $(this).attr("name");
alert(name1);
 });
});
</script>

Name: <input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" class="mytarget"><br />
Age: <input type="text" name="myage" id="myage" class="mytarget"><br />
```

Answer (score 2):

using value get input name

```
 $('input[value="1"]').attr('name');
```

using id get input name

```
 $('input[class="id"]').attr('name');
   $('#id').attr('name');
```

using class get input name

```
 $('input[value="classname"]').attr('name');
   $('.classname').attr('name');  //if classname have unique value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var theName;

theName = $("input selector goes here").attr("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a **single element** preferably you should use the `id` selector as stated on GenericTypeTea answer and get the name like `$("#id").attr("name");`.

But if you want, as I did when I found this question, **a list with all the input names** of a specific class (in my example a list with the names of all unchecked checkboxes with `.selectable-checkbox` class) you could do something like:

```
var listOfUnchecked = $('.selectable-checkbox:unchecked').toArray().map(x=>x.name);
```

or

```
var listOfUnchecked = [];
$('.selectable-checkbox:unchecked').each(function () {
    listOfUnchecked.push($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass class to input tag and access the name value by using class.

```
<input class="test-class" name='xxxxx' value=1>

<script>
    $('.test-class').attr('name');
</script>
```

Or you can also access the value using id.

```
<input id="test-id" name='xxxxx' value=1>

<script>
    $('#test-id').attr('name');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, the best approach would be;

```
<input name="xxxxx" value="1">

$("input[name='xxxxx']).val()
```

Answer (score -2):

For the below line, Initially faced problem with out giving single code that 'currnetRowAppName'value is not taking space with string. So, after that giving single code `'"+row.applicationName+"'`, its taking space also.

**Example:**

```
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs appDelete' type='button' currnetRowAppName='"+row.applicationName+"' id="+row.id+ >

var viewAppNAME = $(this).attr("currnetRowAppName");
alert(viewAppNAME)
```

This is working fine.