# Fetch the value of child/sub element of the data-fieldname attribute using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to fetch the value of the child element of the html data attribute. It returns me object when i call in console

```
$("td").find("[data-fieldname='name']").children("span")
```

but i am not able to fetch the value and it returns undefined when i call

```
$("td").find("[data-fieldname='name']").children("span").val()
```

Can someone suggest me where I am doing wrong?
I have no other distinct way, to select the required span.

Case Html

```html
<pre>
    <td class="listViewEntryValue medium vte-hover-edit-container" data-field-type="string" nowrap="" data-fieldname="name" data-columnname="name" style="position: relative;">
        <span class="vte-display-value dm-test">Mariana Scavelli</span>
        <span class="vte-edit-show-btn cursorPointer" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; display: none;">&nbsp;<i title="Edit" class="icon-pencil"></i></span>
    </td>
</pre>
```

```javascript
$("td").find("[data-fieldname='name']").children("span").val()
```

Comment: A `span` doesn't have a `value` attribute. Use `.text()` instead.

Comment: Also, your HTML is invalid (i.e. `<`pre>`) and `td` elements are not allowed inside of anything but `tr` elements.

Comment: @DeadMan Please reword your question and title as it is very unclear that you are not looking for the value of the span but the value of the `name` attribute of the `span`

Comment: **????** Neither of your `span` elements has a `name` attribute, nor should they. `name` is only for form elements.

Comment: Removed duplicate as OP was not looking for .val()/.text() but instead was looking to get the name attribute value. Question is duplicate of : [**Get attribute name value of <input>**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513809/get-attribute-name-value-of-input) - use that solution on your span.

Comment: @Nope See my comment above. `name` is not only not present in the OPs `span` elements, but it is invalid on a `span` in the first place.

Comment: @Nope Did you read [that link](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/global-attributes.html) you posted? `name` is not listed as a Global attribute. See [this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) for `name`, which clearly shows what elements it is allowed on. `span` is not one of them. `name` is primarially used to set a key for form values when they are transmitted to the `action`.

Comment: @Nope Take the code from [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dLzgn8na/) and run it through the [W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org) and you will get this error: ***Error: Attribute name not allowed on element span at this point.***

Comment: @Nope No one is giving you any smart-a** responses. You posted a link to the Global attribute list as a way of showing that `name` is valid, but `name` isn't on that list. You aren't going to find documentation that says where it's not valid. That's not how documentation works. It's not on the Global list, so it's not Global. The MDN documentation is taken directly from the specs (shown at the bottom of those pages).

Comment: @Nope Here is the [W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/sec-forms.html#naming-form-controls-the-name-attribute) on `name`.

Answer (score 0):

to loop trough all span child elements and get the text inside the span:

```
$("td").find("[data-fieldname='name']").children("span").each(function(){
    let text = $(this).text();
});
```

to loop trough all span child elements and get the name of the element use:

```
$("td").find("[data-fieldname='name']").children("span").each(function(){
    let name = $(this).attr('name');
});
```

span is not an input element and doesn't have a value. `.text()` gets the text inside the span element. Span supports only HTML Global Attributes. More information about these attributes can be read here.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp

As you can see name is not listed here. Therefore name is not supported on span elements in both the html 4.01 and 5 standards. Most likely it will work in most browsers but some browsers that are more strict on the standard might cause issues with your code.

Comment: There are other elements besides `input` that do have a `value`.

Comment: Could have linked jQuery docs on val and text, could have linked W3C documentation or MDN but went with w3schools. <insertGif>

Comment: .text() also return nothing. I want to get the name from the span element

Comment: use `.attr('name')`

Comment: *to get the text node inside the span* ... *`.text()` gets the textnode inside the span*  `.text()` doesn't return a node. It returns a primitive `string`.

Comment: @DeadMan But, neither of your `span` elements have a `name` attribute and that is an invalid attribute on a `span` in the first place.

Comment: Just worth mentioning for OP that `.text()` gets **all** text , including the text from other inline elements within the span. Hence, `<span>Span with text and <sub>sub text<sub> inside</span>` Will return `Span with text and sub text inside`

Comment: Further note that because you are using `.children()` the text you return is all the **combined** text of all `span` elements and not the first or any other specific one only. While on the other hand using `attr()` on `children()` **only** returns the attribute value of the **first** child, which is implicit and terrible code to write. If you intend to only get the first one you can use `.eq(0).attr()`  to make the intend clear.  Neither of this is highlighted in this answer.