# What is the REGEX for ALAA-123456

Tags: html, regex, forms, validation

I'm a newbie at php. 
HTML form is capturing data and mailing it to user via php.
I am trying to make this field have a default value of "ALAA-" and then only permit 6 numbers after "ALAA-". I believe I need the REGex for this but I can't figure out the code. thank you!

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="form_moms_alaa_registration">Doodle Mom's ALAA Number *11 
digits</label>
<input id="form_moms_alaa_registration" type="text" pattern="" 
default="ALAA-123456" tabindex="5"   value="ALAA-" 
name="inputmomsalaaregistration" class="form-control" 
placeholder="ALAA-######" data-error="Doodle Moms ALAA registration 
should have 6 numbers. It is a required field." required>
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the regex you need

```
pattern="ALAA-\d{6}"
```

You could also write it as:

```
pattern="ALAA-[0-9]{6}"
```

I don't think either is more correct than the other, but some people might have opinions about which is more readable.

\d means match any digit. [0-9] means match any character in the range of 0-9 so that is effectively the same thing as \d

The {6} means match exactly 6 repetitions of the preceding character

Comment: Oh, I should have also mentioned! You should not rely entirely on this type of validation, since it is not supported in all browsers. the pattern= argument to the <input> tag is great for providing a better form for the user to inteface with, but you still need to make sure that your PHP script re-validates the input, since you can't be certain that the user's web browser really performed the validation.

Comment: Fantastic James thank you! All my fields are put into an array in the php. Do you have any idea how I would do this validation in PHP.

Comment: No problem, Sylviamc! Glad to help. Check out Ragnar Moro's answer, which includes a PHP snippet that does the same regular expression on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

While sending your client-side HTML form PHP will get the values sent with the  tag how the post method , but first I suggest using a JQuery script to validate the upload data see more information to get values in HTML attributes:
[help about get attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513809/get-attribute-name-value-of-input)
For the server side, PHP manipulates variables that you can treat this value using regex:

```
preg_match('/ALAA-[0-9]{6}/', $_POST['YOURFIELD'], $matches);
```